# Magento2 checkout page refresh gets blank and shows only "Estimate Shipping and Tax"

Tags: magento2, checkout

Hi guys when i am at the checkout page in the payment section and i refresh the browser the checkout page gets blank and only shows "Estimate Shipping and Tax".

i have checked the logs but nothing appears.

Please guys i really need help to get this fixed as we are waiting for this bug to get live.

Comment: May  be some code is created error at checkout.You should check php error log and magento log

Comment: Hi amit thanks for pointing me to the right direction at the moment i only have some php errors and no logs in magento the error i am getting is: [30-May-2018 11:44:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals::setExtensionAttributes() must be an instance of Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsExtensionInterface, instance of Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtension given, called in /var/www/kappanordic.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Api/DataObjectHelper.php on line 125 and defined in /var/www/kappanordic.com/public_html/vendor/magento/modu

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 Checkout page is completely build in Knockout Js. If you are getting blank page on checkout page on page refresh, please check the following points :

1. Browser console for any error. You might get any error in console.(
   This kind of issues comes when you have either overridden any knockout js  file and have some syntax error or undefined binding in knockout template file).
2. Network for failed request, you can check in response for failed request.

As per your comment, It seems that you have added any custom module with custom functionality calling totals. Do remove var/generation files or check your injection in the custom file.

If you will provide brief about your custom changes, It will be more helpful to provide proper solution.